# How can I import Flask-WTF?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I recently installed Flask-WTF and wtforms and wtf, using pip. I just don't know how to import anyone of these in my python file `__init__.py`. I tried:

```
from wtforms import Form
from Flask_WTF import Form
from wtf import Form
from flask_wtf import Form
from flask_wtforms import Form
```

etc...

Most of the Flask Documentations tell me to use `from wtforms import Form`... But it shows `ImportError: No module named wtforms`. It seems like the way you have to import WTF (or however it is called) is not the same anymore. Does anyone know how to import WTF? Thank you!

**Update:**

I searched for Flask-WTF in the python `site-packages`directory, `usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and found out that there is nothing refering to Flask-WTF. It appears that Flask-WTF was not even installed after running `pip install Flask-WTF` or `pip install wtf` or `pip install wtforms`, even tho the terminal returned that it was. Does anyone know why?

Comment: How did you install Flask-WTF? It has a dependency on wtforms, which you appear to be missing.

Comment: I installed it using pip:
pip install wtforms,
pip install wtf,
pip install Flask-WTF,

Comment: And what python was that with? `pip -V` should tell you. Is that the same Python you run Flask with?

Comment: It's all with python2.7, I have two ways to run Flask, automatically trough an apache server, but to test, this time I run `python __init__.py`, where `python` is __python 2.7.5__. I also installed Flask-WTF with `pip`and not `pip3`

Comment: https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: @MisterMM23: yet your script fails to import from `wtforms`, so you need to double-check your assumptions.

Comment: I always do, I'm installing and uninstalling and then reinstalling wtforms, Flask-WTF and wtf, typing `pip install wtforms`, `pip install FlaskWTF`, `pip install wtf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that `pip` doesn't install Flask-WTF, so I did it with `easy_install`, it worked, and I could import what I wanted to import.