# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtforms'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-import, flask-wtforms

Am new in flask , but am getting this error , i tired searching on different questions on stackoverflow but i have found none which work, below is the error am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Huzy_Kamz/PycharmProjects/articles/articles.py", line 6, in <module>
    from wtforms import Form,StringField,TextAreaField,PasswordField, validators
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms'
```

Then the area which the error is expected is in below the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,flash,redirect,url_for,session,logging,jsonify
#from data import Articles
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

from _mysql_exceptions import MySQLError
from wtforms import Form,StringField,TextAreaField,PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from _mysql_exceptions import IntegrityError
from functools import wraps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your imports on line 6 to:

```
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, PasswordField, validators
```

Comment: i changed it but still refused , well i just opened this existing project after an installation of Pycharm , do i need to install them again via pip ?

Comment: You need to make sure that pycharm is using the same installation of python that your pip is linked to - you can change the interpreter in your pycharm settings

Comment: am using miniconda , as my interpereter but i see pip is under , so i tried to install again wtforms in the terminal but its not recognised

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem when I installed a new server with virtualenv.

This is the output when I installed Flask:

```
$ pip install flask
Collecting flask
  Downloading 
....
Building wheels for collected packages: itsdangerous, MarkupSafe
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for itsdangerous ... done

....
Successfully built itsdangerous MarkupSafe
Installing collected packages: click, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, flask
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.10 MarkupSafe-1.0 Werkzeug-0.14.1 click-6.7 flask-1.0.2 itsdangerous-0.24
```

I tried to run minimal script:

```
$ python app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, PasswordField, validators
ImportError: No module named wtforms
```

What I understand is WTFORMS is not installed.
I've search in another post and this works for me ([How can I import Flask-WTF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660399/how-can-i-import-flask-wtf)):

```
$ pip install flask-wtf
Collecting flask-wtf
  Downloading 
....
Collecting WTForms (from flask-wtf)
  Downloading 
....
100% |████████████████████████████████| 174kB 345kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-wtf) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-wtf) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask->flask-wtf) (1.0)
Installing collected packages: WTForms, flask-wtf
Successfully installed WTForms-2.2.1 flask-wtf-0.14.2
```