# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms'

Tags: python, flask, jupyter-notebook, flask-wtforms

can anyone tell my why it's telling me there is no module named "wtforms"

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators
```

[screenshot of code running from jupyter-notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8nNn.png)

Comment: try `pip install WTForms`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the error is most probably because you haven't installed "wtforms" module. This module is available to download from Pypi
run

```
pip install -U WTForms
```

This command will install wtforms and update to latest version.
if this hasn't fixed your problem, feel free to reply

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this topic can help [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtforms'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095019/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-flask-wtforms)

With no further info, it could be that you have forgotten to install the library on your virtual environment using `pip install flask-wtf` after activating it.